# Gain information about objects in an image

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I have a binary image which contains several separated regions. I want to put a threshold on the Area (number of pixels) that these regions occupy, in the way that: a region would be omitted if it has fewer pixels than the threshold. I already have tried these codes (using `bwconncomp`):

```
[...]
% let's assume threshold = 50
CC = bwconncomp(my_image);
L = labelmatrix(CC); 
A = cell( size(CC.PixelIdxList,1) , size(CC.PixelIdxList,2) );
A = CC.PixelIdxList;
for column = 1 : size(CC.PixelIdxList,2)
   if numel(CC.PixelIdxList{column}) < 50, A{column} = 0;
   end
end
```

But at this point I don't know how to convert cell **C** back to the shape of my image and then show it! Are there any tricks to do that?

Is there any easier and straighter way to gain information about objects in an image than this one I used in here?

I also need to know length and width of these objects. These objects do not necessarily have any specific geometrical shape!

Thanks

Comment: I found out that I can use `bwareaopen`instead of all codes I've written above!!! but I'm still stuck in finding a way to calculate lenght and width of individual objects!!! Any idea?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one took the effort to answer my question in here, I found it somewhere else. Now I'm coppying it to here, just in case if anyone novice like me might need to know that.

In order to know length and width of objects in an image:

```
labeledImage = bwlabel(my_image, 8);
regioninfo = regionprops(labeledImage , 'MajorAxisLength', 'MinorAxisLength');
lengths = [regioninfo.MajorAxisLength];   %array
widths = [regioninfo.MinorAxisLength];    %array
```